# [VBA]FileSystemObject to collect video file length

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning people,

I have a need, to know the length (time in HH:MM:SS format) of several video files in several folders. Later I will consume this data in excel or power BI. However, I found a resource in VBA called FileSystemObject. I noticed in the library that I can get the modification date of the file. But actually I would like to collect the length in the video (which you can access via the file properties field). If it is not possible in VBA, I accept references in other languages ​​or tools for study. Link with explanations of feature https://trumpexcel.com/vba-filesystemobject/

Thank you very much

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?58572-Get-duration-of-mp4-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://officetricks.com/excel-vba-get-file-property-author-modified-date-time/

I only updated so I could call as a function:

'Here is the complete list of properties that can be retrieved:

> '0   Name        100 Cell phone      200 Bcc addresses '1   Size
> 101 Nickname        201 Bcc '2   Item type       102 Office location
> 202 Cc addresses '3   Date modified       103 Other address       203
> Cc '4   Date created        104 Other city      204 Conversation ID '5
> Date accessed       105 Other country/region        205 Date received
> '6   Attributes      106 Other P.O. box      206 Date sent '7
> Offline status      107 Other postal code       207 From addresses '8
> Offline availability        108 Other state or province     208 From
> '9   Perceived type      109 Other street        209 Has attachments
> '10  Owner       110 Pager       210 Sender address '11  Kind
> 111 Personal title      211 Sender name '12  Date taken      112 City
> 212 Store '13  Contributing artists        113 Country/region      213
> To addresses '14  Album       114 P.O. box        214 To do title '15
> Year        115 Postal code     215 To '16  Genre       116 State or
> province       216 Mileage '17  Conductors      117 Street      217
> Album artist '18  Tags        118 Primary e-mail      218 Album ID '19
> Rating      119 Primary phone       219 Beats-per-minute '20  Authors
> 120 Profession      220 Composers '21  Title       121 Spouse/Partner
> 221 Initial key '22  Subject     122 Suffix      222 Part of a
> compilation '23  Categories      123 TTY/TTD phone       223 Mood '24
> Comments        124 Telex       224 Part of set '25  Copyright
> 125 Webpage     225 Period '26  #       126 Content status      226
> Color '27  Length      127 Content type        227 Parental rating '28
> Bit rate        128 Date acquired       228 Parental rating reason '29
> Protected       129 Date archived       229 Space used '30  Camera
> model        130 Date completed      230 EXIF version '31  Dimensions
> 131 Device category     231 Event '32  Camera maker        132
> Connected       232 Exposure bias '33  Company     133 Discovery
> method        233 Exposure program '34  File description        134
> Friendly name       234 Exposure time '35  Program name        135
> Local computer      235 F-stop '36  Duration        136 Manufacturer
> 236 Flash mode '37  Is online       137 Model       237 Focal length
> '38  Is recurring        138 Paired      238 35mm focal length '39
> Location        139 Classification      239 ISO speed '40  Optional
> attendee addresses     140 Status      240 Lens maker '41  Optional
> attendees      141 Client ID       241 Lens model '42  Organizer
> address       142 Contributors        242 Light source '43  Organizer
> name      143 Content created     243 Max aperture '44  Reminder time
> 144 Last printed        244 Metering mode '45  Required attendee
> addresses     145 Date last saved     245 Orientation '46  Required
> attendees      146 Division        246 People '47  Resources       147
> Document ID     247 Program mode '48  Meeting status      148 Pages
> 248 Saturation '49  Free/busy status        149 Slides      249
> Subject distance '50  Total size      150 Total editing time      250
> White balance '51  Account name        151 Word count      251
> Priority '52  Task status     152 Due date        252 Project '53
> Computer        153 End date        253 Channel number '54
> Anniversary     154 File count      254 Episode name '55  Assistant’s
> name        155 Filename        255 Closed captioning '56  Assistant’s
> phone       156 File version        256 Rerun '57  Birthday        157
> Flag color      257 SAP '58  Business address        158 Flag status
> 258 Broadcast date '59  Business city       159 Space free      259
> Program description '60  Business country/region     160 Bit depth
> 260 Recording time '61  Business P.O. box       161 Horizontal
> resolution       261 Station call sign '62  Business postal code
> 162 Width       262 Station name '63  Business state or province
> 163 Vertical resolution     263 Summary '64  Business street     164
> Height      264 Snippets '65  Business fax        165 Importance
> 265 Auto summary '66  Business home page      166 Is attachment
> 266 Search ranking '67  Business phone      167 Is deleted      267
> Sensitivity '68  Callback number     168 Encryption status       268
> Shared with '69  Car phone       169 Has flag        269 Sharing
> status '70  Children        170 Is completed        270 Product name
> '71  Company main phone      171 Incomplete      271 Product version
> '72  Department      172 Read status     272 Support link '73  E-mail
> address      173 Shared      273 Source '74  E-mail2     174 Creators
> 274 Start date '75  E-mail3     175 Date        275 Billing
> information '76  E-mail list     176 Folder name     276 Complete '77
> E-mail display name     177 Folder path     277 Task owner '78  File
> as     178 Folder      278 Total file size '79  First name      179
> Participants        279 Legal trademarks '80  Full name       180 Path
> 280 Video compression '81  Gender      181 By location     281
> Directors '82  Given name      182 Type        282 Data rate '83
> Hobbies     183 Contact names       283 Frame height '84  Home address
> 184 Entry type      284 Frame rate '85  Home city       185 Language
> 285 Frame width '86  Home country/region     186 Date visited
> 286 Total bitrate '87  Home P.O. box       187 Description     291
> Masters Keywords (debug) '88  Home postal code        188 Link status
> 292 Masters Keywords (debug) '89  Home state or province      189 Link
> target     293 Primary disk '90  Home street     190 URL     294
> Memory '91  Home fax        191 Media created       295 Machine status
> '92  Home phone      192 Date released       296 Configuration file
> '93  IM addresses        193 Encoded by      297 Audio tracks '94
> Initials        194 Producers       298 Bit depth '95  Job title
> 195 Publisher       299 Contains chapters '96  Label       196
> Subtitle        300 Content compression '97  Last name       197 User
> web URL        301 Subtitles '98  Mailing address     198 Writers
> 302 Subtitle tracks '99  Middle name     199 Attachments     303 Video
> tracks

```
Sub TestGet_Extended_File_Info()
  Debug.Print Get_Extended_File_Info("C:\Downloads\", "Test.mpg", 27)

End Sub

Function Get_Extended_File_Info(strPath As Variant, strFile As String, Optional PropNum As Integer = 3) As String
    Dim sFile, oDir As Object, obja
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Create Shell Object & NameSpace
    Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(strPath)
    Set sFile = oDir.ParseName(strFile)
    
            obja = oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, PropNum)
            If obja <> "" Then
                 obja = Replace(obja, ChrW(8206), "")
                 obja = Replace(obja, ChrW(8207), "")


                Get_Extended_File_Info = obja
   Set oDir = Nothing

                Exit Function
            
            End If
   Set oDir = Nothing
 End Function
```